# How can i get the value from array without using regex in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

From the array of string I need to get string which starts with age- followed by maximum of 2 digit number and optional '+' sign.

Ex: age-1, age-22, age55, age-1+, age-15+

Following is my array:

```
arr = ["vintage-colllections","age-5"]
         or
arr = ["vintage-colllections","age-51+"]
```

I will extract age "age-5" or "age-51+"  from the array.

I tried following things:

```
arr.find {|e| e.include?"age-"}
```

Works well for other scenarios but in above the 1st element of array also includes (vint)**age-** failing there.

```
arr.find { |e| /age-\d*\+?/ =~ e}
```

Works fine but I am trying to avoid regex.

Is there any other better approach ?.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is it always the second element in the array?

Comment: @Arc676 no I have some other elements also coming

Comment: What about `if e starts with "age-"`? Are there any other elements that start with that?

Comment: I'm curious why you don't want to use a regex here, as it is clearly the way to go. Is it just an exercise?

Comment: @Cary sort of exercise :P

Comment: @Arc676 good suggestion man. I also hope that there wont be any other elements starts with age-.

Comment: Your problem is not that you want to extract `"age-5"` or `age-51+` from strings contained in those two particular arrays. That is, since you know they are there, what is the point of extracting them? Presumably you want to do something like the following: given an array of strings, match each element of the array with a substring that begins "age-", is followed by a greedy match of one or more digits, optionally followed by `+`". You need to state your question in such a manner.

Comment: @cary Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to ask question more generic way in future.

Comment: I was not just making a suggestion for the future; you need to clarify the question! Do you want to match `"age-"`? `"page-"`? `"age-+"` (as your regex does)? `"age-77#"`? `"age-4+3"`? You cannot expect readers to infer the matching rules by example. If this were a spec for code, there would be blood on the floor. Guess whose?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103621/discussion-between-praveenkumar-and-cary-swoveland).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `start_with?`:

```
arr.find { |e| e.start_with?("age-") }
```

Comment: That was good and almost 98% correct solution. I will hope some other elemnts not starts with "age-" (i.e :some stupid string like : age-rope).

Comment: Though regex is the best solution in this case, you may try something strange like `arr.find { |e| e.gsub("age-", '').to_i > 0 }`

Answer (score 2):

I must grit my teeth to not use a regex, but here goes. I assume the question is as described in a comment I left on the question.

```
def find_str(arr)
  arr.map { |str| str_match(str) }.compact
end

def str_match(str)
  return nil unless str[0,4] == "age-"
  last = str[-1] == '+' ? -2 : -1
  Integer(str[4..last]) rescue return nil
  str
end

find_str ["cat", "age-5"]     #=> ["age-5"] 
find_str ["cat", "age-51+"]   #=> ["age-51+"] 
find_str ["cat", "age-5t1+"]  #=> [] 
find_str ["cat", "xage-51+"]  #=> []
```